# MaTeX, font size, and PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending, matex

I want to create plots in Mathematica where all labels have font sizes which match those in a LaTeX document.
I start by defining

```
Needs["MaTeX`"];
texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 12}
```

Now, if I export a simple plot

```
Export["test1.pdf", 
       Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
            BaseStyle -> texStyle,
            ImageSize -> 400]]
```

the font sizes match those in my document. However, if I include a plot legend

```
Export["test2.pdf",
       Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
            BaseStyle -> texStyle,
            ImageSize -> 400,
            PlotLegends -> Placed[MaTeX[{"\\sin(x)", "\\cos(x)"}], {0.6, 0.8}]]]
```

the font size in the plot is too small. This might have to do with the fact that Mathematica makes the second plot smaller (independent of MaTeX).

Comment: Minor note: `MaTeX` does use a 12 pt font size by default, but instead of relying on that (it may change in the future!) I would set it explicitly too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MaTeX and is essentially a duplicate of

- [How to export graphics in “Working” style environment rather than “Printout”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093559/695132)

(But can't be marked as such because that question is on StackOverflow, and it was asked before the creation of Mathematica.SE)

However, MaTeX does come with a nice tutorial on preparing figures to size, which explains this issue.  Enter `MaTeX/tutorial/PreparingFiguresToSize` in the address bar of the documentation browser.

[image]

In short, when an expression with head `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` is exported, it retains the sizes. However, when any other visual expression is exported to PDF, it will use the styles from the [`PrintingStyleEnvironment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintingStyleEnvironment.html). The default is `"Printout"`, which downscales everything to 80%. This applies to all sorts of expressions that format content in notebooks, such as `Row`, `Grid`, `Labeled`, etc.  *It also applies to [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)*, which is the head of any graphics containing a legend.  This is because `Legended` uses the same underlying [boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookStructure.html) as `Grid`, `Column`, `Labeled` and several others: [`GridBox`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridBox.html).

Yes, this is very annoying and very hard to figure out if you are not aware of it.

The workaround is to set the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` to be the same as the style environment used for on-screen display:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

This setting will persist until you restart the Front End.  If you use `$FrontEnd` instead of `$FrontEndSession` then it persists even across restarts.  I do not recommend doing this though, as there is a good reason for the `"Printout"` environment downscaling to 80%: this environment is used when printing notebooks or converting notebooks to multi-page PDFs. Without the downscaling very little content fits on a single page.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. The computer I am using is locked down very much and therefore I am using an old version of MaTeX. I could not find the tutorial in the documentation.

Comment: @kalix If you can use Mathematica, then very likely you can install MaTeX. If you have M11.2 or later, just evaluate `PacletInstall["https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/releases/download/v1.7.4/MaTeX-1.7.4.paclet"]`. Otherwise use the install script on MaTeX's GitHub page

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was afraid to update because recently other users with the same privileges as I did have problems installing MaTeX (I don't remember the exact error and the admin was not able to fix it). Installing worked without problems for me some time ago so I was afraid to trigger the same problem when updating. Debugging these problems is sometimes annoying without admin privileges.

Comment: @kalix You can suggest to the admin to contact me if he has trouble with the package. I can help him install it system-wide and advise on compatibility with various Mathematica versions.